# How can i update column value using ui-grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ui-grid table plugin.i want to update count value if user enter same id. if id is not same i want to update whatever user enter in the count textbox value. count will increase only if user enter same id.
push function only should work if user enter new id otherwise only count increase.
how can i do it?. I need anyone help.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope',
function($scope) {
    $scope.gridOptions = {};
    $scope.Delete = function(row) {
        var index = $scope.gridOptions.data.indexOf(row.entity);
        $scope.gridOptions.data.splice(index, 1);
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs =[{ field:"Id", displayName: "Id"},{ field:"Display", displayName: "Display"},{ field:"Count", displayName: "Count"}];

       $scope.addedid=0;     
       $scope.myVaridarr=[];
      $scope.addid = function(myVarid,countVar){

    $scope.addedid =  +$scope.addedid+ +countVar;

          var addToArray=true;
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.myVaridarr.length;i++){
    if($scope.myVaridarr[i]===myVarid){
    addToArray=false;

    alert("Id already is there"); 
     $scope.gridTwoValue =
      {
                "Id": myVarid,
        "Display": "Carney",
        "Count":  $scope.addedid 
      };
     $scope.gridOptions.data.push ( $scope.gridTwoValue ); 
    }
    }
    if(addToArray){alert("New Id");
    $scope.myVaridarr.push(myVarid); 
    $scope.gridTwoValue =
      {
                "Id": myVarid,
        "Display": "Carney",
        "Count":  $scope.addedid 
      };
    $scope.gridOptions.data.push ( $scope.gridTwoValue ); 
    }};  }]);
```

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/3ryLqa9e/452/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                $scope.gridOptions.data[index] = {
                    "Id": myVarid,
                    "Display": "Carney",
                    "Count": $scope.addedid

                };
```

Comment: Tomgal..your script is not working. So can u edit my jsfiddle?

Comment: calculation is wrong becuase if user enter same id that's count value should be add with present count textbox value.

Comment: Just remove plus sign